# Flutter does not recognize my package (Unused impor error)

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ecpX.png
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CWri.png

Hey there I was making a todo app on flutter and my app is working correctly. Then, suddenly I write some other codes after that flutter did not recognize my homepage package and saying that 'unused import' but I'm using it.How can I fix this

Comment: `unused import` doesn't mean it doesn't recognize it. It also isn't an error. It simply means you are not using any of the import in that file and you can safely remove that import

Comment: but If I remove that import Android Studio screen stays Black

Comment: You probably removed the code that adds your HomePage to the screen

Comment: Can I send my code to you to find out where did I fail?

Comment: You can add it to the question

Comment: Can you check out my code? I added into the question

Comment: Can you show main.dart? the error should be there

Comment: I hope this works,I added the new image you can check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow you removed the loading of the HomePage from main.dart. Inside `MaterialApp` there should be something like:

```
home: const HomePage()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not setting the HomePage.dart to home attribute in main.dart.
Just add

> `home: const Homepage()`

attribute inside the Material app.
You will be good to go.
Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Flutter dont see import but you can make a game for it.
create a page and its page make a class

after come to main.dart and call that class, flutter will import and will see your all unused import package.

Comment: class Sayac with ChangeNotifier{
  int sayacDegeri = 0;

  sayaciArttir(){
    sayacDegeri++;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  sayaciAzalt(){
    sayacDegeri--;
    notifyListeners();
  }


}

Comment: import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:imdatx/sayac.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(
            providers: [ ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_)=>Sayac()),],
            child: const MyApp()));
}

Comment: why not to update your answer with these comments?